# R collapse duplicate pairs (in any order) across dataframe columns and edit 3rd column?

Tags: r, dataframe, overlap

I used rbind to join 2 dataframes, with a column denoting its source, resulting in

```
    from | to | source
1     A    B      X    
2     C    D      Y
3     B    A      Y
...
```

I would like to look for overlapping pairs, regardless of "order", combine those pairs, then edit the source column to something else, e.g. "Z".

In the above example, rows 1 and 3 would be flagged as overlapping, so they will be combined and modified.

So the desired output would look something like

```
    from | to | source
1     A    B      Z    
2     C    D      Y
...
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
unique(
  transform(
    transform(
      df,
      from = pmin(from, to),
      to = pmax(from, to)
    ),
    source = ave(source, from, to, FUN = function(x) ifelse(length(x) > 1, "Z", x))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  from to source
1    A  B      Z
2    C  D      Y
```

Comment: Thanks! This is getting close.  But the result I got from this was a dataframe that ONLY had source="Z". Also, to clarify, all the values in "from" and "to" are strings, not numbers, will that interact as intended with functions like "pmin" and "pmax"?

Comment: @LarryCai If you want to create new variables, you can try `ifelse(length(x) > 1, toString(x), x)`

Comment: `ifelse(length(x) > 1, toString("Z"), x)` seems to behave the same - the resulting dataframe only has Source="Z", it did not retain the non-overlapping pairs with Source="X" or "Y".

Comment: @LarryCai No, not `toString("Z")`, see `ifelse(length(x) > 1, toString(x), x)`

Comment: My bad! I just tried it exactly `...toString(x)...`, the resulting dataframe appears to contain the exact same Columns "from" and "to", but this time the "source" column is ALL "A, A". There was no "A, B" or "B, B" permutations. Similarly, it did not retain non-overlapping pairs with source="X" or "Y".

Comment: @LarryCai Could you `dput` your data? I don't know that is your desired output with your real data.

Comment: My bad! Turns out I accidentally corrupted my data somewhere, losing all the source= "B"s somehow. After re-loading the original df, `ifelse(length(x) > 1, toString(x), x)` DOES work as intended! Thanks!

Comment: @LarryCai Great that it works. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
set.seed(1)

df=data.frame(
  "from"=sample(LETTERS[1:4],10,replace=T),
  "to"=sample(LETTERS[1:4],10,replace=T),
  "source"=sample(c("X","Y"),10,replace=T)
)

   from to source
1     A  C      X
2     D  C      X
3     C  A      X
4     A  A      X
5     B  A      X
6     A  B      X
7     C  B      Y
8     C  B      X
9     B  B      X
10    B  C      Y
```

and then

```
tmp=t(
  apply(df,1,function(x){
    sort(x[1:2])
  })
)

t1=duplicated(tmp,fromLast=F)
t2=duplicated(tmp,fromLast=T)

df[t2,"source"]="Z"
df[!t1,]

  from to source
1    A  C      Z
2    D  C      X
4    A  A      X
5    B  A      Z
7    C  B      Z
9    B  B      X
```